# Occasional long pause when running docker

Tags: windows, docker

I'm running docker on Windows.

When I run a command like `docker ps -a` or even just `docker --version` there is a 10 second pause before it produces any output.  This seems to happen only when the machine has been idle for a while (for maybe 20 seconds or more?)  Then subsequent executions of `docker --version` will be quick and responsive.  If I let the machine sit for a bit, then it goes back to exhibiting the long pause before output again.  If I run another docker command immediately after, then it responds quickly again.

I looked through my path to make sure there was nothing weird.  I checked power/performance settings.  I don't really know where else to look.  It's only docker that is behaving like this.  Other apps on the machine work fine.  So I don't think it has anything to do with the disk or memory or anything like that.  I have 32 GB of RAM and <10 GB of it is in use.

This seems a bit mysterious, I know, I'm sorry.  Any suggestions of things that I could try to get more information and ultimately figure this out?

It's annoying that half the time when I execute a docker command I have to needlessly wait 10 seconds before the command will start.

- Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825
- Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Since it doesn't look like it can be related to being short of RAM, another guess might be that docker uses a HDD and that your power options turn it off when it's not being used. If it's not an SSD, turning back on can take a few seconds (probably not 10 though, more like 5 in my experience).

Comment: Yes, my power settings have "turn off hard disk after 20 minutes".  It definitely doesn't take 20 minutes so there's an inconsistency there, but I'll switch the PC to an Ultimate Performance, always-on configuration and give it another go.  Thanks @NicolasB for the tip.

Comment: Sadly, changing power options didn't help.  :(  Other ideas?

Comment: @Wyck did you see the potential solutions in this github issue: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1936  It's either reinstall or possibly excluding processes and folders from Windows Defender

Comment: @diginoise, yes, I've seen that page.  Nothing solved my issue, but the advice to use procmon has pinned it down to a 10-13 second period of inactivity of docker.exe during a `docker --version` call.  The last activity before the hiatus was RegCloseKey HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup and the first after was CreateFile C:\Windows\System32\samcli.dll.  Relevant stuff right before were TCPIP-related accesses of netapi32.dll, wkscli.dll, netutils.dll, secur32.dll and logoncli.dll. But I don't know if that's just when it started to contact the docker daemon or what.

Comment: @Wyck - somebody suggests running the commands via console (or PowerShell) as administrator. Did you try that too? (suspicious looking call to secur32.dll and logoncli.dll)

Comment: @diginoise, there's still a 10+ second delay even when running as administrator.

Comment: @Wyck have a look at this one: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2131   here the quick tests are to run using local (not domain-ed) user account or switching IPv6 off.

Comment: @diginoise, tried both those things.  No improvement.  Although I did leave a comment and some diagnostic info on that issue at GitHub.